# MOSFET does not fully turn off in flyback converter

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, flyback, oscillation

I have this prototype flyback converter on a breadboard. However there is a problem. [image]

As you can see from the oscilloscope captures of Vds when I use Vin=25V the MOSFET turns off in 3 us. [image]

But in Vin=50V it takes 11.5 us and the Vds oscillates at around 122.5 kHz.

[image].

The components are able to work with much higher voltages as stated in their datasheet. Also, the HCPL-3101 datasheet states that it can switch 3000 pF load in 0.5 us which is does for turn on but not for turn off.

As you can see in this figure my driver pulse is very sharp t_rise=32ns and t_fall=38ns

[image]

Is there any way to improve the turn off time and more importantly prevent Vds oscillations?

Comment: The oscillation is due to the converter entering DCM as the output diode is no longer forward biased. An oscillation between your transformer inductance and mainly MOSFET output capacitance will occur. You can use this as a benefit by switching on the valley of the oscillation, saving a bit of switching losses. Search for "flyback valley switching". Moreover, building a flyback converter on a breadboard is a very tall order. Consider designing a proper PCB for it with solid ground plane.

Comment: That oscillation is completely normal in a flyback converter.

Answer (score 3):

> *when I use Vin=25V the MOSFET turns off in 3 us.*

The MOSFET will turn off quickly but, you have leakage energy left in the primary that needs to dissipate via your primary snubber and, this will take several micro-seconds to disappear. While that is happening, the voltage will glide down to 0 volts and give the appearance that the MOSFET is turning off slowly.

> *But in Vin=50V it takes 11.5 us and the Vds oscillates at around 122.5
> kHz.*

Again, the MOSFET will be turning off quickly but now your converter has entered discontinuous conduction mode (DCM) and you have the extra effect where the leakage inductance "rings" with the MOSFET drain-source capacitance. This is very, very normal.

> *Is there any way to improve the turn off time and more importantly
> prevent Vds oscillations?*

You are trying fix something that "[ain't broke](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it#:%7E:text=Leave%20something%20alone%3B%20avoid%20attempting,is%20risky%20and%20might%20backfire)".